# When did office chairs get their fifth wheel?

Tags: furniture

Modern swiveling office chairs almost universally have five wheels on five legs, while vintage chairs often have only four. The fifth wheel adds a lot of stability against tipping over; the physics and geometry of this arrangement must have been obvious quite a long time ago. [This related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/230751/why-do-most-office-chairs-have-5-wheels) on a sister site shows that the change was in place by the 1980s, as well as naming reasons motivating it.

When did the fifth wheel and leg become normalized in the manufacture of office chairs?

Comment: Cursory googling produced an example from the 1920s, and a steady increase after that.

Comment: "The fifth wheel adds a lot of stability against tipping over" - having the same length of the legs only. You could make four longer legs with the same stability. Five legs win not stability, but free place - four legs will cause problems to people passing by - people will stumble over longer legs. Also, with five legs you always put most of your weight on 2 legs instead if one. And the legs needn't be so hard or thick.

Comment: Related, from physics.stackexchange: [Why do most office chairs have 5 wheels?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/230751/why-do-most-office-chairs-have-5-wheels).